# Django makemigrations: ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field

Tags: django, django-migrations

i got this error.

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 125, in handle
    migration_name=self.migration_name,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 43, in changes
    changes = self._detect_changes(convert_apps, graph)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/autodetector.py", line 110, in _detect_changes
    self.old_apps = self.from_state.concrete_apps
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 158, in concrete_apps
    self.apps = StateApps(self.real_apps, self.models, ignore_swappable=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 236, in __init__
    raise ValueError(msg.format(field=operations[0][1], model=lookup_model)) ValueError: Lookup failed for model referenced by field systech_account.User.companies: systech_account.Company
```

every time i try to

> python manage.py makemigrations

in my (Ubuntu). but when i try to run it on my Windows and my colleagues in their(Ubuntu) **it works fine**. (*we share the project via Git repo). they can make the migrations successfully. we are wondering why is this happening to my PC alone.

Notes:

- I'm the only one experiencing this within my team.
- When i create/update model, i can't makemigrations. So, i have to push my changes to the repo for them to pull and makemigrations in their computer (WHICH THEY ARE NOT ENCOUNTERING ANY ERRORS)in their end and push the migration file to repo so i could migrate it.
- "Everytime we need to make any changes to a model we need to pull from the repo first for any latest migration file then make the migration file so they will have succeeding numbers, because--"
- if we don't our migration files would have so many errors because of dependencies with other migrations then we have to delete all our migration files, delete the database and do a makemigration again.(We don't know how to handle this, honestly)

Solutions we tried:

- Deleted the local database
- Reinstalled PSQL
- Reinstalled Django
- Reinstalled Python
- Deleted the repo and cloned again
- Deleted all the migration files(This works but why?, we don't want to delete all migrations because it will also affect our live site.)

---

1. How do we solve this?

Thanks! :)

Comment: its seems that systech_account.Company couldnt be found , could u share you project folder structure or maybe the orm mapping.

Comment: this is happening to my end only, in my other team mates they can makemigrations successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess here that `systech_account.Company` is a model thats in an app that hasn't been loaded yet whilst trying to create a migration for a different app.

If this is true its probably solvable by first running

```
makemigrations app_that_has_company_in_it
```

before running your other `makemigrations`.

But this isn't the solution.

The fact that you and your colleagues are all trying to do the same migration tells me that you don't store the migrations in your source control which is the real problem here.

Doing this *does* stop these errors from ever occurring (at least for me/us) and makes it much quicker when trying to make migrations since there aren't any repeated steps. If you're worried about merge conflicts with these, you needn't worry, django is very clever.

Comment: Thanks, i already tried that but its not working. whenever i create/update a model a let my teammates do it in their PC to make the migration file and pull the migration file from the repo so i could migrate. there is something wrong with my PC, we could just not pinpoint it. i also tried from other account and clone the repo there but still no luck

Comment: @Binsoi - You may want to look in your gitignore then to see if theres anything in there that shouldn't be (i.e settings.py)

Comment: This is the content of our gitignore :) 

/.project
*.pyc
env/pyvenv.cfg
env/
winenv/
winvenv/
root/local_settings.py

Comment: @Binsoi - that settings.py looks suspicious... I'd check that with your colleagues version

Comment: we have the same settings, its strange that if i temporarily remove the migration files. i can create new migrations successfully.